# On the LowerBound for the number of edges of a simple connected graph on $n$ vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-verification

We know that if $G$ is a simple graph on $n$ vertices and if $G$ has $k$ components then the number of edges $m$ of $G$ has the lower bound:

$n-k\leq m$.

The proof of one of a reference book on Graph Theory is this: [image]

I need some help on understanding the proof. In particular, what is the induction hypothesis in the proof?

Is it suppose $m\geq n-k$? If this is the case, then for $m_0>m$ then $m_0\geq n-k$ so we consider $m_0$ less than $m$? Is this a valid mathematical induction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps, here we used the concept of backward induction.